# How to make 2 buttons with different sounds (FLASH action script)

Tags: flash

I am trying to make 2 buttons (then more) that make different sounds. I have the buttons created and the sounds in the library, but it seems my action code is not working. If I just use the first segment, I get sound 16 to play on key16 button. But when I add the second (duplicate and modified) key 17 code, nothing happens for either:

```
key16.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

function playSound(event:Event) {
   var mySound:sound16 = new sound16();
   var myChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();
};

key17.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

function playSound(event:Event) {
   var mySound:sound17 = new sound17();
   var myChannel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
key16.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound1);

function playSound1(event:Event) {
   var mySound1:sound16 = new sound16();
   var myChannel1:SoundChannel = mySound1.play();
};

key17.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound2);

function playSound2(event:Event) {
   var mySound2:sound17 = new sound17();
   var myChannel2:SoundChannel = mySound2.play();
};
```